# PHP email not sending and not displaying contact form on firefox

Tags: php, email

Hello its bit confusing for me so just asking..

1. I have a contact us form setup on pop-up box ! Its working fine on google chrome but on Firefox it just show a shadow and don't display the pop-up `lightbox`.
2. I have setup email script to use `google captcha` for verification (`re-captcha`) , but when i fill form and click send it don't give error and submit.

but i never receive email at my inbox.. i tried with Gmail , Hotmail and few others..

So i can't understand where the problem is, Please can anyone check my code and tell is its my core error or its my server error and how to fix these issues.

**Here goes my sendmail.php code:**

```
   <!-- for re-captche -->
 <?php
  require_once('../recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    if(!$_POST) exit;
    $to         = "###";
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $message    = $_POST['message'];

    $subject    = "You've been contacted by $name";

    $content    = "$name sent you a message from your enquiry form:\r\n\n";
    $content   .= "Contact Reason: $message \n\nEmail: $email \n\n";

    if(@mail($to, $subject, $content, "From: $email \r\n Reply-To: $email \r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")) {
        echo "<h5 class='success'>Message Sent</h5>";
        echo "<br/><p class='success'>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted and someone will contact you shortly.</p>";
    }else{
        echo "<h2 class='failure'>Sorry, Try again Later.</h2>";
    }
  }
  ?>
  <!--  For contact us form validation and sending -->
```

Comment: Did you validate your html?

Comment: do you run it on localhost or on server? Make sure that an emailserver is installed.

Comment: what's this @mail function? I just know  mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header) ...

Comment: ahhhh..   what to validate in html ? second.. output is "success"  i just don't get email..  3rd its on server.. so  i hope server has mail server pre-installed.. and i can't understand @abimelex your question..

Comment: @JohnKim You're suppressing errors by using `if(@mail`. Remove the `@`, then run the script again and tell us which error messages you receive, then come on back here and share it.

Comment: @abimelex The `@` symbol suppresses error messages, once the form handler goes through its executed steps.

Comment: i tried doing that,.. got no mail yet.. but again i get sent successful message... crap ! :P   i will wait a bit hoping i receive the mail this time.

Comment: @JohnKim Check your Spam.

Comment: @JohnKim Also try to add `\r\n` in `$subject    = "You've been contacted by $name";`. To show as `$subject    = "You've been contacted by $name\r\n";`

Comment: @JohnKim So, any luck with my last suggestions?

Comment: Yo man after removing @ it works ! Shit man i just forget it up !!  Thanks a lot..

Comment: @JohnKim You can **accept** my answer by clicking on the **checkmark** next to it, since it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@` symbol in:

```
//-v
if(@mail($to, $subject, $content, "From: $email \r\n
Reply-To: $email \r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")) {
```

and change to:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $content, "From: $email \r\n
Reply-To: $email \r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")) {
```

Comment: Yea that solved my issue.. but another issue.. like the site is showing contact form in chrome but not showing anything in firefox..  what the heck is that ?

Comment: @JohnKim That's either an HTML and/or CSS issue. Unless you've got some fancy JS happening in there. Can you give me the URL, or ask another question on SO about it with your form and associated code, and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @JohnKim It's next to impossible for me to test this, without your form (full code).